# Prove that the spectrum of an operator on L^p (\mathbb{R}) is the boundary of unit cỉrcle

Tags: lp-spaces, spectra

I am working on finding the spectrum of some bounded linear operator but I have no idea. Could you please help me to prove the following problem:

Let $X=L^p (\mathbb{R})$ and for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we define

$$T(t) : X \rightarrow X$$
by $\left [ T(t)(f) \right ] (s) = f(s +t), \forall s \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that the spectrum $\sigma \left ( T (t) \right )$ is $\partial B(0,1)$ if $t\neq 0$.

Thank you so much.

Comment: "boundary of unit ball" is a weird expression in this case. The spectrum is a set complex numbers, so calling it the "unit circle" would be more conventional I think.

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed it.

Comment: Actually, I have no idea to work on this problem.

Comment: have you tried using the definition of the spectrum?

Comment: Yes, I did. I choose $s=0$ then $f(t) = \lambda t$. It follows that $f$ is a linear function and its integral on $\mathbb{R}$ is infinite.